# Ajustar vetor pós remoção de elemento

Tags: c

Então, imagine que já existe uma função que cadastre alunos e existe essa `struct` de alunos abaixo e uma variável que conte quantos alunos cadastrados temos e a constante que controle o tamanho do array de struct do tipo `aluno(N_ALUNOS)`

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[25];
    int matricula;
    float notas[2];
    char situacao[10];
} Aluno;

Aluno Alunos[N_ALUNOS];

int alunosCadastrados = 0;
```

Essa função(é o problema) recebe a posição excluída do vetor, a ideia da função é que a partir de uma posição excluída do vetor todos elementos que estejam em posição superior voltem uma posição, vetor esse que é o citado acima

```
void atualizaArray(int posExcluida){
    // Se a posição excluida não for a última
    if(posExcluida < alunosCadastrados - 1){
        // Percorre todo vetor
        for(int j = 0; j < alunosCadastrados; j++){
            // se o índice atual for maior que a posição excluida do vetor
            if(j > posExcluida){
                Alunos[j - 1].matricula = Alunos[j].matricula;
                strcpy(Alunos[j - 1].situacao, Alunos[j].situacao);
                Alunos[j - 1].notas[0] = Alunos[j].notas[0];
                Alunos[j - 1].notas[1] = Alunos[j].notas[1];
                strcpy(Alunos[j - 1].nome, Alunos[j].nome);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Em testes feitos eu estava definindo `N_ALUNOS` como 3 e ao preencher os 3 índices do vetor eu tentava apagar o primeiro índice e ao verificar os dois índices que sobraram , ficavam repetidos com os valores do 2 índice, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código faz o que se pretende, de puxar todos os elementos uma posição para trás embora esteja mais complicado do que seria necessário. Agora lembre-se que o que você fez na realidade é copiar todos as informações de cada aluno uma posição para trás, mas o tamanho do vetor continua igual. Por isso a ultima posição, tem informação repetida, mas é suposto ser desconsiderada, que é algo que não está a fazer. Precisa de dizer que a quantidade de alunos cadastrados diminuiu fazendo:

```
alunosCadastrados--;
```

E em todos os locais onde usa o vetor, tem de usar apenas até à quantidade de alunos cadastrados que tem no momento, assim:

```
for (int i = 0;i < alunosCadastrados;i++){
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Simplificando a sua função para remover e incluindo a instrução que falta:

```
void atualizaArray(int posExcluida){
    if(posExcluida >= 0 &&  posExcluida < alunosCadastrados - 1){
        for(int j = posExcluida; j < alunosCadastrados - 1; j++){
        //              ^--- começa na posExcluida  ^--- termina uma antes do fim
            Alunos[j].matricula = Alunos[j + 1].matricula;
            strcpy(Alunos[j].situacao, Alunos[j + 1].situacao);
            Alunos[j].notas[0] = Alunos[j + 1].notas[0];
            Alunos[j].notas[1] = Alunos[j + 1].notas[1];
            strcpy(Alunos[j].nome, Alunos[j + 1].nome);
        }
        alunosCadastrados--; //ajustar o tamanho
    } 
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/gaoWUB)

A diferença nesta versão, para além da instrução que ajusta o tamanho, é que começo o `for` diretamente na posição excluída, e atribuo os valores com o elemento da frente. Como me guio pelo elemento da frente não posso ir até ao fim, e tenho de terminar um antes do fim.

Em contraste com a sua versão, ficou com menos um `if` dentro do `for` e também só percorre os alunos a partir da posição excluída, tornando-se assim mais eficiente. Aproveitei e inclui o teste para evitar que a posição a excluir possa ser negativa.